# XamlParseException with image source

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have this image in a XAML file of my project:

```
<Image Source="/my.namespace;component/Resources/document_plain.png" Margin="5" />
```

The image is in a directory `/Resources/document_plain.png` at the root of my project folder. The settings of the image are:

[image: Build Action: Resource, Copy to Output: Don't copy, Custom Tool: empty, Custom Tool Namespace: empty, File Name: document_plain.png]

But, when running a debug instance, I immediately get an XamlParseException:

> The string "/my.namespace;component/Resources/document_plain.png" in the attribute "Source" could not be converted to type "System.Windows.Media.ImageSource". 
>   The file or assembly "my.namespace, Culture=neutral" or a dependency could not be found. The system cannot find the file.  Error in object "System.Windows.HierarchicalDataTemplate" in markup file "MyProject;component/view/mainwindow.xaml", line 20, position 12.

Which strikes me as strange, because IMHO the project is correctly set up. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the assembly name is "MyProject", so your string should probably be `Source="MyProject;component/Resources/document_plain.png"`.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I think the issue was introduced as I changed the namespaces of the projects. So, the string must always contain the `Assembly name` set in the properties of the project. Then it finds all the images correctly.

Comment: You can write that as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @dlev Can you write the comment as an answer? Then I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cudos to dlev from the comments:

> It looks like the assembly name is "MyProject", so your string should probably be Source="MyProject;component/Resources/document_plain.png"